# keyframes animation doesn't work for some reason

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have some text in html that I want to animate

```
<div class="sofa-text inner-text">
    <h1>Sofa, we have cool sofas</h1>
</div>
<div class="light-text inner-text">
    <h1>our stand light is out-standing</h1>
</div>
```

and here's CSS

```
.inner-text {
       display: none;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       background-color: black;

       position: absolute;
       transition: 1s;
       transform: translateY(200%);

       animation-name: slide-up;
       animation-duration: 2s;
       animation-delay: .5s; 
}

@keyframes slide-up{
    0% {
        transform: translateY(200%);
    }
    100% { 
        transform: translateY(0); 
    }
}
```

and I wanted to display this animation, after the button was clicked

```
let $sofaText = document.querySelector('.sofa')
let $lightText = document.querySelector('.light')

let showSofa = () => {
    $sofaText.style.display = 'flex'
}
let showStand = () => {
    $lightText.style.display = 'flex'
}

$sofaBtn.addEventListener('click', showSofa)
$standBtn.addEventListener('click', showStand)
```

However this doesn't work. I tested step by step and problem was in @keyframes. I even added -webkit but it still didn't work. I have no idea what's wrong with this

Comment: if you change the div to flex it won't cause the animation to work

Comment: @ATP oh really? I didn't knew that.

Comment: the only thing you are doing on the button click is to change the display = 'flex'

Comment: it still doesn't work ;-;

Comment: do you think that `display:none` will stop your animation and when its removed it will start?

Comment: your animation has already run, toggle a class instead a style reset, so your animation starts  when class is added and display too. possible approach : https://jsfiddle.net/jredz5qc/

Answer (score 0):

It's working you just can't see it because `display:none;`

```js
function tran(){
   let t = document.querySelector('.sofa-text');
   t.classList.add("anim");
   t.style.display = "flex";

}
```

```css
.inner-text {
       display:none;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       background-color: black;

       position: absolute;
       transition: 1s;
       transform: translateY(200%);


}
.anim{
       animation-name: slide-up;
       animation-duration: 2s;
       animation-delay: .5s; 
}

@keyframes slide-up{
    0% {
        transform: translateY(200%);
    }
    100% { 
        transform: translateY(0); 
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="tran()">click</button>
<div class="sofa-text inner-text">
    <h1>Sofa, we have cool sofas</h1>
</div>
<div class="light-text inner-text">
    <h1>our stand light is out-standing</h1>
</div>
```